# How can i store list of values entity framework with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to store list of Ids of workers in my `Project` entity.

```
public class Project
{
    [Required] [Key] public Guid id { set; get; }
    ...Other fields
    [AllowNull] public List<Guid> workers { set; get; }
}
```

But MySql doesn't support array type and when i'm configuring model

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(x =>
        {
            x.HasKey(y => y.id);
            x.Property(y => y.workers);
        });
    }
```

i have an error `The property 'Project.workers' is of type 'List<Guid>' which is not supported by the current database provider.`
So, what is the best way so store array type with EF?

Comment: Look like you are applying code first. This [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) may helps.

Comment: Databases don't have list columns (generally), they have other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Conversion to combine list to string and deserialize It.
like below;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(x =>
        {
            x.HasKey(y => y.id);
            x.Property(y => y.workers).HasConversion(x => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x), // to converter
                                   x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guid>>(x));
        });
```